# ggplot legend -- how to make the line segment longer?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I love ggplot, but over the last couple of years I've run aground on this problem a couple of times -- and I've not been able to find recommendations how to fix it.

I do note that there is a question regarding line widths -- but the answer to that question does not allow me or any other reader to solve this line segment *length* problem.

I've been trying to force the legend to use a larger line segment so that the viewer can identify which factor is which.

```
require(ggplot2)

tmp2 <- NULL
plotted <- c(seq(1,55), seq(1,110,2), seq(1,165,3))
nam <- c(rep("num1", 55), rep("num2", 55), rep("num3", 55))
tmp2 <- data.frame(nam, plotted)
tmp2$indx <-  seq(1, dim(tmp2)[1])

gr <- ggplot(tmp2, aes(x = indx, y = plotted, colour=nam)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=nam),size=1.5) +
  labs(title = 'Block 2 N2O', x = "example X", y = "yaxis") + 
  theme_bw()

gr
```

This produces a legend with line segments that are inadequate to identify the line style (once there are quite a few lines on the graph)...
[image]

How do I make those legend ling segments longer?

Thanks!

Matt

Comment: maybe increase the key size : `gr + theme(legend.key.size = grid::unit(5, "lines"))`

Comment: Fantastic!!!! Thankyou!

Comment: Actually this is not a duplicate. The previous question regards legend.keysize.width. Now when you search for line length width questions are not going to be found -- and that previous question does not answer a line length question.

Comment: user2449710 ; the answers in the linked question answer yours which is why i linked to it (two use `theme(legend.key.width = unit(5,"cm"))` and describe it, and I think `key.width` is better than `key.size` which I suggested ^^)). By marking it as a duplicate it means that if someone searches for legend segment length (or similar terms to what you used) they will be directed to an answer that they can use.

Comment: Except that key.width changes the line width -- not the length of the segment. So, in this case it is not a solution.